# Calculator created with Python

Tags: python

I'm new here in this "world".
I tried to create a calculator with Python,here's the code.
When I try to run it,IDLE gives me errors,can you help me,please? :D

Header 1

```
print("Options")
print("Type 'add' to add two numbers")
print("Type'subtract' to subtract two numbers")
print("Type'multiply' to multiply two numbers")
print("Type'divide' to divide two numbers")
print("Type'quit' to exit")
user_input = input(": ") 

if user_input == "quit":
   break

elif user_input == "add" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1+num2)
   print("The answer is " + result)

elif user_input == "subtract" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1+num2)
   print("The answer is" + result)

elif user_input == "multiply" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1+num2)
   print("The answer is " + result)

elif user_input == "divide" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1+num2)
   print("The answer is " + result)
else:
   print("Unknown command")
```

Comment: please include the error in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (you don't have loop so use exit() rather than break, also use the right operators for add, divide, sub-struct, multiply.

```
from __future__ import division # to support division
print("Options")
print("Type 'add' to add two numbers")
print("Type'subtract' to subtract two numbers")
print("Type'multiply' to multiply two numbers")
print("Type'divide' to divide two numbers")
print("Type'quit' to exit")
user_input = raw_input(": ")

if user_input == "quit":
   exit()  #break is uesd in loops

elif user_input == "add" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1+num2)
   print("The answer is " + result)

elif user_input == "subtract" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1-num2)
   print("The answer is" + result)

elif user_input == "multiply" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1*num2)
   print("The answer is " + result)

elif user_input == "divide" :
   num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
   num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
   result = str(num1/num2)
   print("The answer is " + result)
else:
   print("Unknown command")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the break statement here:

```
if user_input == "quit":
   break
```

You can only use a break statement within a while and/or for loop.
The solution is to replace the break statement with print() or exit() instead.

For your program to be more effective (and to be able to use the break statement), you could execute your if,elif and else statements within a while loop:

```
print("Options")
print("Type 'add' to add two numbers")
print("Type'subtract' to subtract two numbers")
print("Type'multiply' to multiply two numbers")
print("Type'divide' to divide two numbers")
print("Type'quit' to exit")

while True:
    user_input = input(": ") 
    if user_input == "quit":
        print('Program terminated')
        break

    elif user_input == "add" :
       num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
       num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
       result = str(num1+num2)
       print("The answer is " + result)

    elif user_input == "subtract" :
       num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
       num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
       result = str(num1+num2)
       print("The answer is" + result)

    elif user_input == "multiply" :
       num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
       num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
       result = str(num1+num2)
       print("The answer is " + result)

    elif user_input == "divide" :
       num1 = float(input("Insert a number: "))
       num2 = float(input("Insert another number: "))
       result = str(num1+num2)
       print("The answer is " + result)
    else:
       print("Unknown command")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are implementing a break that is not in a while loop.
Breaks must occur in a while loop. So a way of getting around this problem is by saying:

```
if user_input == "quit":
   exit()
```

Example2:

```
import sys
if user_input == "quit":
       sys.exit()
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

```
if user_input == 'quit':
    #break
    pass
```

Comment: This will not achieve what the OP wants.